# How to model map<string, map<string, int>> in ProtoBuffers 3

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, marshalling

I'm using Go to implement an API endpoint that should return data that looks like this:

```
{
    "object1s": [
        {
            "object2": {
                "key1": {
                    "key3": 1,
                    "key4": 2,
                    "key5": 3
                },
                "key2": {
                    "key3": 4,
                    "key4": 5,
                    "key5": 6
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "object2": {
                "key1": {
                    "key3": 7,
                    "key4": 8,
                    "key5": 9
                },
                "key2": {
                    "key3": 10,
                    "key4": 11,
                    "key5": 12
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I model this with proto3?

I have this:

```
message SubObject {
  map<string, map<string, int32>> object2 = 1;
}

message ResponseMessage {
  repeated SubObject object1s = 1;
}
```

But I believe the syntax `map<string, map<string, int>>` is invalid.
So what is the correct way to describe `SubObject`?

Comment: Just define `map<string, int>` as another message type.

Comment: Not_a_golfer. Exactly How? Can you show me please? Because if I understand it correctly, when I do that, I will have to give the variable `map<string, int>` a name. And then that name will appear in the object. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired way isn't supported yet. 
Right now, only way to do this, is to create a `message` type to hold the inner `map` field.

```
message InnerObject {
    map<string, int32> object3 = 1;
}

message SubObject {
    map<string, InnerObject> object2 = 1;
}

message ResponseMessage {
    repeated SubObject object1s = 1;
}
```

So, you have to modify your return data as follows,

```json
{
    "object1s": [
        {
            "object2": {
                "key1": {
                    "object3": {
                        "key3": 1,
                        "key4": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Reference : [Issue#4596](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4596)

Comment: Please show how to define the protocol buffer. That is my question.